# Steps to install sharepoint 2013 on Win 7 - VMWare/VHD boot

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have did some research that i can't have SP 2013 installed on Windows 7.

Can i install a vmware/vhd boot with win 2008/2012 server and then SP 2013.If Yes how to get started?

Any resources or tips would be appreciated.
    Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. If you are using Windows 7. My favourite is VMware but you can use Virtualbox aswell. Remember that you should have at least 16 GB ram and it is recommended to have a second harddrive to install the guest OS (prefer SSD).

There is numerous of guides to set up a development environment for Share Point on internett.

For example here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/490811/SharePoint-2013-Setting-Up-A-Clean-And-Recoverable

One of my favourite books on this topic:
[http://www.amazon.com/SharePoint-2013-Development-Machine-ebook/dp/B009Y4QZT8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009Y4QZT8)